# Title in FragmentDialog can't be displayed fully

Tags: android

I create custom Fragment and set to it some title:

```
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().setTitle(R.string.personalAuthDialogMessage);
        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personal_pass_dialog, null);
        personalPasswordEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.personalPasswordEditText);
        buttonPositive = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.personAuthButtonPositive);
        buttonNegative = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.personAuthButtonNegative);
        buttonPositive.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonNegative.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }
```

When I invoke it in my activity everything is Ok, except the size of title does not fit on the screen. It looks like this:
[image]

Original message is "Please, confirm your password".

**UPD.** Code of layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:id="@+id/personalDialogLayout"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/personalPasswordEditText"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="@string/confirmOk"
            android:id="@+id/personAuthButtonPositive" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="@string/confirmCancel"
            android:id="@+id/personAuthButtonNegative" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your layout code which you are inflating in your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You have differents options to handle that. Basically you can force the layout of the dialog to increase its width :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:id="@+id/personalDialogLayout"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

but this solution isn't convenient because some screen are smaller, if you want your title to change it may not fit, etc ...

So what you can do is to remove the title from the Dialog, with this code :

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
```

and handle the title yourself :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:id="@+id/personalDialogLayout"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/personalPasswordEditText"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="@string/confirmOk"
            android:id="@+id/personAuthButtonPositive" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="@string/confirmCancel"
            android:id="@+id/personAuthButtonNegative" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and set the title :

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personal_pass_dialog, null);
TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialogTitle);
title.setText(R.string.personalAuthDialogMessage);
```